# Cross-referencing label and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing

I am using a label for referencing. I just added my table of contents and saw the label is used as chaptertitle. How could I fix this?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}

\let\orichaptermark\chaptermark
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\label{chap:#1}\orichaptermark{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[label]{Chapter name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This looks strange! This means that you want to refer to a chapter by its literal name. This is possible, but it's better to use a symbolic name for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's possible to make label names with chapter names it's better to refrain from this procedure.

The optional argument of `\chapter` is reserved (in standard LaTeX document classes) for the short entry to the table of content (and page headers), especially useful for long chapter names.

The `\cref` command inserts the correct reference name (chapter), if the `cleveref` package is loaded. (Load it as last one, even after `hyperref`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{cleveref}
%\let\orichaptermark\chaptermark
%\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\label{chap:#1}\orichaptermark{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter name}\label{first:chapter}
\blindtext

 \chapter[Second chapter]{A very long second chapter title}\label{second:chapter}
\blindtext

In \cref{first:chapter} we saw that ... 


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In addition, `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` would be a good idea

Comment: I would like to add the label fast and without many text. I thought the renewcommand was fine for this. I don't use long chapter names that need to be changed in the TOC.

I might better use:
\chapter{Chapter name}\label{chap:chapter}
See \ref{chap:chapter} Name, page \pageref{chap:chapter}

Comment: In this case omit the `[]` pair after `\chapter` then.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set the first set of [] for short TOC title and the second set of [] for label? So \chapter[shorttitle][label]{Chapter title}

Comment: @RemcoSwienink: No, at least not for the standard document class `report`. There is only **one** optional argument `[]`, designed for the short toc title. The `memoir` class however provides for a 2nd option, but I am unsure about it's meaning at the moment